# Chartjs question: How to give left margin on legend

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs-2

question about chartjs 3.x

[image]

above image what I have right now.

and below is what I want to achieve.

[image]

I want to give some margin to the legend so that it aligns with the y axis.

I researched and tried adding a plugin like this

```
   const legendMarginPlugin = {
        id: "legendMarginLeft",
        afterInit(chart) {
            const fitValue = chart.legend.fit;
            console.log(chart)
            chart.legend.fit = function fit() {
                fitValue.bind(chart.legend)();
                let width = (this.width += 200);
                return width;
            };
        },
    };
```

but this did not work.
(probably this way does not work when the legend is positioned at the bottom..)

Does anyone know how I can give left margin on legend?

Comment: Maybe you can try to set fullSize: false, in the legend config.

Comment: fullSize:false worked on bar and line chart but not on donut chart, do yo know why?? @user2057925